# Smart Filter Bar does not appear

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to use [SmartFilterBar](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.ui.comp.smartfilterbar.SmartFilterBar) as follows:

```
<VBox fitContainer="true">
    <smartFilterBar:SmartFilterBar id="JobProfileOverviewFilter" entitySet="ProfileSet">
        <smartFilterBar:controlConfiguration>
            <smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration key="Item"></smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration>
        </smartFilterBar:controlConfiguration>
        <smartFilterBar:layoutData>
            <FlexItemData shrinkFactor="0"/>
        </smartFilterBar:layoutData>
    </smartFilterBar:SmartFilterBar>
    <smartTable:SmartTable id="JobProfileOverview" entitySet="ProfileSet" tableType="ResponsiveTable" useTablePersonalisation="true"
        showRowCount="true" enableAutoBinding="true" smartFilterId="JobProfileOverviewFilter" header="Business profiles"
        class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding" app:useSmartToggle="true">
        <smartTable:customToolbar>
            <OverflowToolbar design="Transparent">
                <ToolbarSpacer/>
                <OverflowToolbarButton icon="sap-icon://order-status" tooltip="Order status" text="Order status" press="onStatus"/>
            </OverflowToolbar>
        </smartTable:customToolbar>
        <!-- layout data used to make the table growing but the filter bar fixed -->
        <smartTable:layoutData>
            <FlexItemData growFactor="1" baseSize="0%"/>
        </smartTable:layoutData>
        <Table mode="MultiSelect"></Table>
    </smartTable:SmartTable>
</VBox>
```

The problem is, the filter does not appear on the screen.
[image]

the cutout from the metadata:

```
<EntityType Name="Profile" sap:content-version="1">
    <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="ItemId"/>
    </Key>
    <Property Name="Item" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="300" sap:unicode="false" sap:label="Role" sap:creatable="false"
        sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
    <Property Name="Connector" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="32" sap:unicode="false" sap:label="System" sap:creatable="false"
        sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
    <Property Name="Descn" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" sap:unicode="false" sap:label="Description" sap:creatable="false"
        sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
    <Property Name="ValidFrom" Type="Edm.DateTime" Nullable="false" Precision="7" sap:unicode="false" sap:label="Valid From"
        sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
    <Property Name="ValidTo" Type="Edm.DateTime" Nullable="false" Precision="7" sap:unicode="false" sap:label="Valid To" sap:creatable="false"
        sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
    <Property Name="Status" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="8" sap:unicode="false" sap:label="Expiration Status"
        sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
    <Property Name="Selected" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="1" sap:unicode="false" sap:label="Boolean" sap:creatable="false"
        sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
    <Property Name="ItemId" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="50" sap:unicode="false" sap:label="Object ID" sap:creatable="false"
        sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
    <Property Name="ItemType" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="6" sap:unicode="false" sap:label="Item Type" sap:creatable="false"
        sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
</EntityType>
<EntitySet Name="ProfileSet" EntityType="YGAC_ACCESS_MANAGER_SRV.Profile" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:deletable="false"
    sap:pageable="false" sap:content-version="1"/></EntityContainer>
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

I have enabled the filter now
[image]

But it does not appear in SmartFilter:
[image]

I have to enable it in the filter option:
[image]

Why the filter fields do not get shown as default?

Comment: xml looks fine to me. You created your Service via SEGW or CDS ? If SEGW set `sap:filterable="true"` and try again. (you can do that in segw [Task 1: Add sap:filterable annotation to properties](https://blogs.sap.com/2013/06/20/how-to-develop-query-options-for-an-odata-service-using-code-based-implementation/))

Comment: I have updated the post

Comment: your smartfilterbar expects annotations. For example show filter xy at position xy. I prefer creating local annotations in webide when not working with cds. Search for tutorials how to use the [webide annotation modeler](https://blogs.sap.com/2020/06/18/create-fiori-application-with-fiori-elements-and-local-annotation-modeler-without-javascript-coding-for-ui-elements/)

Answer (score 1):

Try to add other parameters, for example:

```
  <smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration
    key="Item"
    mandatory="auto"
    preventInitialDataFetchInValueHelpDialog="false"
    visibleInAdvancedArea="true"
    controlType="auto"
    displayBehaviour="idAndDescription"
    label="Item"
    index="1"></smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration>
```